# Trying to get maven up and running on intellij with java/javafx

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to get maven to work properly on my computer. Until now I have mostly avoided using it but for the time being i need to get it up and running. I want it working with javafx/java in general.

I have checked various guides trying to get it working but with no luck.

1. Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler & Bytecode version/Project Bytecode version
2. Matched with Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK & Project Language Level

I get the error: 
Error:java: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.

This is a continual problem.

What I do:

1. Create a javafx project
2. Import all dependencies and refer them to the right location with VM options
3. Right-click given project folder -> Add framework support -> Maven

Appreciate any simple solutions. Links I have checked and tried.

Comment: Have you seen https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/?

Answer (score 0):

In your pom you need to simply change the target/source to java 6 or higher.

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to set up the pom file? currently, the files contents look like this for me:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>untitled3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        
    </project>

Comment: Put it within the <project> tags. Honestly this is something you can Google.